# Multiple bindings of SLF4J

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, solr

I have the following error in spring boot application:

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

I went to the link and tried to remove slf4j-simple-1.7.13 and logback-classic from the pom I thought was importing this but it did not work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solrj.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solrj.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>

                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Solr J version:

```
    <solrj.version>5.2.1</solrj.version>
```

How can I determine if this is the correct offending module? Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

The pom file uses a spring boot parent we created ourselves. Maybe that is where the exclusions need to take place?

Here is the dependency tree for org.slf4j:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ some-service ---
[INFO] com.company.io.some.service:some-service:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.company.io.commons:commons-mongo:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.company.io.commons:discovery-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.company.io.commons:commons-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.com.company.io:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- com.company.io.commons:commons-utils:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:5.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] +- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:jar:1.50.5:test
[INFO] |  \- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.process:jar:1.50.2:test
[INFO] |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:test - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |        \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |           \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.company.io.spring.boot.starter:central-config-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.io.config:config-client:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.6.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.10; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.19.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.company.io.spring.boot.starter:ana-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.company.io.auth:ana-client:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.company.io.commons:commons-jersey:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.company.io.commons:rules-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- com.company.io.commons:event-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  +- com.company.io.commons:data-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |     +- com.company.io.commons:notification-schema:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- com.company.io.commons:commons-statsd:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.13:compile (version managed from 1.7.12)
[INFO] |     |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.12; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- io.company.on.spring.boot.starter:metrics-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlet:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.7; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile - version managed from 1.7.5; omitted for duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding an exclusion for `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple` in your POM, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.io.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ana-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```